# Can you have multiple Webform handlers trigger on sumisstion?

Tags: webforms, civicrm

I have a need to run some preprocessing on data using a custom Webform handler before I want the data to be handled by the CiviCRM handler. Is there a reason both handlers won't run one after the other?

[image]

Comment: You can definitely run one handler after another if they are both enabled. The weight should determine order of processing. Is there some reason you think that's not working?

Comment: Thanks @AlfredArmstrong. I've determined that it was working but I had missed a piece of config.